# My Own Application Send Button

Tags: docusignapi

I am building an application in which the sender has the sender's view, and then he from the sender's view, adds recipients, message subject, documents and tabs and after that using our own application send button and save draft button, the envelope can be saved or sent.

If I just change the status to "send" using an api call, it won't work since the docusign server is not aware of the recipients and the documents the sender has entered, so, how do I create my own send button and save draft button for a view that is initially empty and the user enters everything manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just let the sender use the functionality (Send) that's already built-in with the Embedded Sender view?

Comment: Because it also has a previous link, a save as draft link, etc that we want to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think want you want to do is feasible. i.e., unless/until the user clicks the "Save Draft" link within the Embedded Sender view, DocuSign will not persist (store) any of the changes the user has made to the Envelope(recipients, documents, email info, tabs, etc.).

Comment: Is there anyway for me to create a save draft function instead of having the user click save draft?

Comment: Not if the Sender's using the "Embedded Sender" view to add recipients/documents/tags/etc.  As long as the sender's adding the information directly/manually using the "Embedded Sender" view, then the only way that information can be persisted is by the Sender taking action (clicking "Save Draft" link or "Send" link) within the Embedded Sender view itself.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, is there anyway to hide the Sign on Paper button when using the embedded senders view?